Contemporize "milk run" for supermarket culture
I want to use "milk run" for a long elevator ride with frequent stops.
But "milk run" is about a milkman's morning route through the neighborhood. Drive,stop,milk to the stoop, drive,stop... In a time when we get our milk from the supermarket, the phrase is perhaps antiquated?
Well I feel it is.
What could replace it?
UPDATE
Thanks to all those who pointed out that my use of 'milk run' is incorrect.
I'm seeking a term for a journey that has frequent stops along the way. Bonus points for a terms that suggests the frequent stopping is frustrating.

Do you mean another term for getting milk from a milkman, or a single term for a trip to get milk from a supermarket?

@alphabet Ah there we go. It really is an antiquated term. A "milk run", as used in the olden days, meant a trip that was frequently interrupted by stops.
It has nothing to do with milk.
It's clearly an expired allegory.

Is the phrase perhaps antiquated? Have a look at Google Ngrams... More popular than ever. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=milk+run&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=3

A milk run is defined by it's repetitiveness. You run the exact same route every day. The many-stops part is optional. I think the usage really changed with the Post WWII Milk Run bringing milk from Ireland to England in Lancasters and Liberators.

@StephenBoston Ah. I've never heard the term before in either the literal or the metaphorical sense.

https://derbosoft.proboards.com/thread/3820/milk-air-lift-1947-1948

The broadened usages of 'milk run'  usually involve routine and uneventfulness (in the lack of drama sense), with 'frequent stops' a secondary connection. The usual mode of transport involved is the plane, and sometimes the train. See CD, M-W etc.

An elevator ride with frequent stops (when you keep looking at the indicator to see if it's your floor) might, like a subway ride, seem interminable: continuing for too long and therefore boring or annoying. But it is not a noun.

Wrong idiom, and no, that's not what the idiom is about. A milk run is a boring, repetitive, and time consuming job delivering stuff (or gathering stuff). It is usually at least daily. It has been applied to bus routes, train routes, and air logistic operations since well before WWII. The Burma Hump and Berlin Airlift resupply efforts were milk runs (as was the literal milk lift from Ireland to England), with aircrews recycling as fast as they could. An elevator ride, however an eternity it may seem, simply doesn't merit the term. And it isn't productive work.
The term for an elevator that can be dispatched to all floors (and a train that stops at every little jerkwater on the line) is a local. Not sure how you make an idiom of it, though - the vertically challenged part of your commute?

I was going to ask what an "elevator ride" was, it really refers to an elevator in an apartment building, it's not an idiom?

@Mari-LouA  Well, I hope so. But the way my week has been going, I'm not sticking my neck out.

Thanks, you're a sport :)

Local could, indeed, be an apt term for 'a long elevator ride with frequent stops', but its effectiveness depends on the audience being familiar with commuting by train in a system in which there is a distinction between local and express trains (such as the New York City subway). At other places, local may be used in contrast to long-distance; at such places the analogy with what the OP has in mind would be lost.

A local in NYC means a slow train (i.e. subway) as oppposed to an express train. I lived in NYC for 15 years, and I know we say express elevator. too (one that does not stop at every floor), but I don't recall the others being locals.

The full Oxford English Dictionary has...

milk run = milk round noun colloquial
a routine trip or service, usually involving calls at several places, esp. an early morning train or flight;
spec. (U.S.A.F. slang), a safe or uneventful mission; a flight completed without risk or incident.

Unsurprisingly, I guess, I didn't know that second sense. And although the first definition includes routine, I've always thought of it as a reference to frequent stops, rather than "early morning" and/or "uneventful".

To confuse matters further, there is a logistics term of art that differentiates hub and spoke models from alternative strategies for aggregation and distribution. The pizza delivery guy delivers pizza from one source to all the community. The Door Dash guy delivers food from three restaurants to 1/3 of the community. That's called a milk run model. It can be a more efficient system overall.

I recall a year or two ago I had a brief conversation with the guy who delivers prescription medicines from our local pharmacy direct to people's door. He said something like "It's a real milk run - you're stopping every few hundred yards for another delivery". That would have been around midday, but he definitely went on to say he'd be going out again later, because he needed recipients to sign for their package, and some people were out at work while we were talking. So no implication of "early morning round". Me, I was praising the fact that it kept many customers' cars off the road.

Conversely, I had always thought that a milk run was an easy, uneventful job, the 2nd def. A baby could do it. As opposed to a milk round. The dictionary conflates the two, but IMO they are different.

In the U.K. the term "milk train" is applied to the last train leaving (for example) Euston railway station in London, where it literally stops at virtually every station along the line in order to pick up milk churns.
If you've been at the theatre or out on the town the "milk train" on the "milk run" will be the last train out of the station. Source: experience
An interminable journey implies an apparently endless journey. Just like the last train that stops at every station on the line, it seems to take forever to get to your destination.

That's actually close to the original idea of the milk bottler going to fetch the milk from farms. That way they could make sure they only bought as much as they could deliver in one day. So the "many stops" idea lives on in some places.

daily grind

hard, boring work or duties that you have to do every day:

She's looking forward to retiring and ending the daily grind of working in an office.
I find the daily grind of being a headteacher very dull.
Cambridge Dictionary



This is a possible answer to the question formulated in the title, but not to the body of the question (daily grind would hardly be an apt term for 'a long elevator ride with frequent stops').

In a creative write-up, you can probably borrow  a phrase from railways. A train that stops at every station is called a Stopping Train,
stopping-train in Cambridge dictionary
Maybe even a commuter train or a local  train will  capture the essence.

stop-and-go

A stop-and-go activity is one in which there are short periods of movement with regular interruptions

Cambridge Advanced Learner's
